# SQL Group By Max of Group By Count

Tags: sql, count, max

This is my initial count query, and result set. I just cant work out how to get the max query working.

The Query

```
SELECT QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION, COUNT(QM_QUOTE_NUM) as Quotes
FROM QM (NOLOCK)
WHERE QM_CUST_CODE in ('H-PAT001', 'H-ABI002')
GROUP BY QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION
```

The Results

```
QM_CUST_CODE    QM_XX_REGION    Quotes
1  H-ABI002     0           1
2  H-PAT001     0           3
3  H-ABI002     1           397
4  H-PAT001     1           1509
5  H-PAT001     2           1
```

--The problem
How to I get only the rows 3 and 4 to return, as these are the customer codes by region that have the MAX no of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH recordsList
AS
(
    SELECT  QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION, COUNT(QM_QUOTE_NUM) as Quotes,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER  (PARTITION BY QM_CUST_CODE 
                                ORDER BY COUNT(QM_QUOTE_NUM) DESC) rn
    FROM    QM
    WHERE   QM_CUST_CODE in ('H-PAT001', 'H-ABI002')
    GROUP   BY QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION
)
SELECT  QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION, Quotes
FROM    recordsList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get two rows having highest Quotes count then try this:

```
Select Top 2 * From
(
SELECT QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION, COUNT(QM_QUOTE_NUM) as Quotes
FROM QM
WHERE QM_CUST_CODE in ('H-PAT001', 'H-ABI002')
GROUP BY QM_CUST_CODE, QM_XX_REGION
)tbl
Order By  Quotes Desc
```